# MongoDB query with perl with $and and $nin

Tags: perl, mongodb

I am attempting to use the MongoDB Perl driver to do a query on a collection with this kind of document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("519fcfa59fb9d97874000001"),
    "variant" : {
        "alt" : "T",
        "ref" : "C",
        "chr" : NumberLong(1),
        "pos" : NumberLong(13302),
        "rsID" : "rs180734498"
    },
    "genotype" : {
        "GT" : "0/0"
    },
    "sample" : {
        "ID" : NumberLong(8751),
        "tags" : [
            "hiseq",
            "exome",
            NumberLong(8751)
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is the snippet of my BAD perl code:

```
  my $hom_count = $exomevars->count({
    '$and' => [ {
          "variant.chr" => $chr,
          "variant.pos" => $pos,
          "variant.ref" => $ref,
          "variant.alt" => $alt,
          "genotype.GT" => qr/1\/1/,
          "sample.tags" => { '$nin' => \@these_tags }
          } ]
         });
```

My collection is indeed indexed on these fields -

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "variant.chr" : 1,
        "variant.pos" : 1,
        "variant.ref" : 1,
        "variant.alt" : 1,
        "genotype.GT" : 1,
        "sample.tags" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "vars.exomevars",
    "name" : "variant.chr_1_variant.pos_1_variant.ref_1_variant.alt_1_genotype.GT_1_sample.tags_1"
}
```

...but my script hangs and no query happens. I am pretty sure it is the $nin/sample.tags part of the query that is my problem, if I take out my \@these_tags and hard code some text like this, it still hangs without a query...

`"sample.tags" => { '$nin' => ["stuff","things"] },`

Also made sure my @these_tags array is working with Data::Dumper - seems I'm getting it right...

```
print Dumper \@these_tags;
    $VAR1 = [
              'Please',
              'help',
              'stackoverflow',
              'friends'
            ];
```

It's not the `qr/1\/1/` - I've used this query before and it works fine. As an example, here is an earlier version of the script where I was only trying to exclude based on a single string, this query works beautifully:

```
  my $hom_count = $exomevars->count({
      '$and' => [ {
          "variant.chr" => $chr,
          "variant.pos" => $pos,
          "variant.ref" => $ref,
          "variant.alt" => $alt,
          "genotype.GT" => qr/1\/1/,
          "sample.ID" => { '$ne' => $this_sample }
          } ]
         });
```

It's only when I added the `sample.tags` array to the collection and now try the `$nin` operator, whelp, I'm lost...

I've tried taking out the whole $and clause, still nothing. I'm using MongoDB v2.4.3 on a 4-node shard setup and the MongoDB-0.700.0 perl driver.

Any pointers on where I've gone wrong? Any additional info I should provide?

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try the full query, but it's definitely not a problem with `$nin`. Using your sample document, I was able to run these:

```
perl -MMongoDB -E 'say MongoDB::MongoClient->new->get_database( "so" )
->get_collection("vars")->count( { "sample.tags" => { "\$nin" => [ "hiseq", "foo" ] } } )'

0

perl -MMongoDB -E 'say MongoDB::MongoClient->new->get_database( "so" )
->get_collection("vars")->count( { "sample.tags" => { "\$nin" => [ "narf", "foo" ] } } )'

1
```

What happens if you try to run this query in the shell, and tack on an [explain](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/)? How big is the collection?

Edit:

This bit from your log is interesting:

```
$nin: [ [ "Please", "Help", "stackoverflow", "friends" ] ]
```

You've got an array with an array in it, but it should be:

```
$nin: [ "Please", "Help", "stackoverflow", "friends" ]
```

Are you certain your array has what you think?

Comment: it's a collection of 318534850 docs... count worked in the shell, explain is giant so here it is on pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/thKuXXjZ)

Comment: Well it definitely looks like the indexes are working fine. Anything interesting in the `mongod` logs when you run the query from Perl?

Comment: here is the log from one of the shards when trying from Perl: [http://pastebin.com/cb90T1UQ](http://pastebin.com/cb90T1UQ)

Comment: @caddymob, Updated the answer with some insight from your logs.

Comment: oops, that is my bad - I tried `"sample.tags" => { '$nin' => [\@these_tags] }` and that was the output. So lets try again without the brackets as originally posted... [Pastie3](http://pastebin.com/n866gG7Q)

Comment: OK for fun I set `$MongoDB::Cursor::timeout = -1;` in the Perl script, got through 4 queries so far, out of 13932 staged... Queries are taking ~ 105,000ms (almost 2 mins! each!) [http://pastebin.com/thjZg2S8](http://pastebin.com/thjZg2S8). Before going to the tags array and just doing a $ne "somestring" they were ~5ms...and this is only 1 of the queries, there is another still to go, just trying to get this running right before I go big.

Comment: any ideas? I am sure about the array, its not an array of arrays, that was a test that I pastebin'd erroneously as I was trying everything I could think of... It's `$nin: [ "Please", "Help", "stackoverflow", "friends" ]` as originally posted... See the `print Dumper`

Comment: Oops, sorry - forgot about this question. I don't have any other ideas at the moment but let me think about it again in the morning. :)